# Xcode - How to find the middle date between two dates

Tags: objective-c

I would like to find the middle date between two dates, in objective c.

Comment: Are you looking for an Objective-C or a C/C++ answer? XCode provides compilers for both, but the answers would be different.

Comment: I'm looking for Objective-C answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `NSDateComponents` and `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`, this is what I use and it works pretty good. Make sure to watch out for years that are leap years.

```
-(void)getBetweenDates:(NSDate *)startDate andEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *offset = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offset setDay:1];

    NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSDate *curDate = startDate;
    while([curDate timeIntervalSince1970] <= [endDate timeIntervalSince1970]) 
    {
        [dates addObject:curDate];
        curDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:curDate options:0];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",dates);

    [offset release];
    [calendar release];
}
```